# Inking in XAML with C# in a Windows Universal App

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, universal

Does anyone know how to Ink in XAML? I have done loads of research, and I am new to the language, but I have no idea as of how to do this. I have not found anything on inking in XAML. Any info ranging from fundamentals of the API to basic XAML starting places will help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the official samples.

Windows 8.1: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-81-Input-Ink-baf6b5e9

Windows 10: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SimpleInk